# Spring boot rest mvc json parser is not validating input json data which is illegal or has trailing data

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

In my rest client i am passing the below JSON request data:

```
  { 
    "jobName":"test1", 
    "source":{ "name":"prod1","type":"teradata"}, 
    "target":{ "name":"prod2","type":"teradata"}, 
    "objects":{ "name":"table1"}<br/>
    } 
junkdata ; @#%$@#%
```

So the extra "junkdata ; @#%$@#%" not got validated by the rest client or by the spring jackson out-of-the box message converter.
I did debug the code, the spring HttpServletRequest body has the complete data including the junk data. As such its not failing, the spring is ignoring the junk data and converting the starting JSON data into Java object.
I did try by adding annotations like @JsonFormat for @RequestBody in rest controller calls (@RestController). But its not validating seems the Spring out-of-the box message converter jackson is not validating the incoming request JSON data properly.

Comment: So the `junkdata` is outside the actual JSON object. right?. Which is the client that you are using to send this data to the server?

Comment: Yes the junkdata is outside of the actual JSON object. I am using Mozilla FireFox, i have even tried Chrome also.

Comment: Can you share the restcontroller implementation and the client code that sends the request? Also the JSON is invalid. You can check JSON validity on [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

After working on different ways i got the solution using Google gson.jar, @Pete yes i have validate the JSON input which is invalid. 
The google gson api is validating it properly, we need to use the custom message converter to validate it in the rest WebMvcConfigurationSupport class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.teradata.datamovement.rest.controllers",
        "com.teradata.rest.controller" })
public class RestControllerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
       @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            log.debug("Adding custom message converter.");
            converters.add(new AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object>(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, new MediaType("application", "*+json")){
                @Override
                protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz,
                                              HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
                    try{
                        log.debug("Converting and validating the http request body data.");
                        String httpRequestBody = convertStreamToString(inputMessage.getBody());
                        log.debug("Http request body data:"+httpRequestBody);
                        return new Gson().fromJson(httpRequestBody, clazz);
                    }
                    catch(JsonSyntaxException e){
                        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Invalid input JSON data: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    } 
                }
                private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
                    if (is != null) {
                        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                        try {
                            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                            int n;
                            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            is.close();
                        }
                        return writer.toString();
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                @Override
                protected boolean supports(Class clazz) {
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                protected void writeInternal(Object t, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
                        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
                     outputMessage.getBody().write(new Gson().toJson(t).getBytes());
                }
            });
        }

}
```

But the weird thing i have noticed is that its working only if i make it as anonymous class  or by adding the class with in the same file. If i create this custom message converter out side this RestControllerConfiguration.java file, then its not validating it.
Here is the example:

```
{
"jobName":"test1",
"source":{ "name":"prod1","type":"teradata"},
"target":{ "name":"prod2","type":"teradata"},
"objects":{ "name":"table1"}
}
junkdata ; @#%$@#%
```

This will get validated, and will throw error like

```
{"message":"Invalid input JSON data: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 7 column 1; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 7 column 1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this issue (failing on trailing tokens or data) is fixed in the spring jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1583 
using DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS, Here is the code sample to fix the issue:

```
@Configuration
public class RestControllerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS, true);
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
    }
}
```